# Can Varnish backend be specified by stand-alone app?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Currently we have 3 applications (varnish backends):

1. Eshop
2. CMS
3. Routing - app which returns status code of which backend should be chosen to hit.

The main idea between this is that we have the same domain for Eshop and CMS. And all links are stored in MySQL database. So to decide where should varnish hit we are using some *routing* app.

If we are hitting routing backend in the **vcl_recv** we are checking status in **vcl_backend_response** and switching the backend like that:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (591 == beresp.status) {
        set bereq.backend = eshopDirector.backend();
        return (retry);

    } elsif (592 == beresp.status || 593 == beresp.status || 594 == beresp.status) {
        set bereq.backend = cmsDirector.backend();
        return (retry);
    }
}
```

After *retry* we are not caching results because **vcl_recv** stage is not hit again to identify if results has to be retrieved from the cache or from the backend itself.

So the question here, is there any way to identify which backend has to be used from **vcl_recv** stage, to get cached results afterwards? 
Maybe it's possible to make CURL request from there to get status from the routing app and handle it accordingly?

Comment: Not sure if it is the right approach but if you want to make curl request: https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-curl

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Talking about the approach it's for sure it's not good.. But I haven't found better solution yet.

However I'm thinking about static VCL generator of all URL and it will choose which backend should handle the request, but I'm still looking forward to solve it with routing app, because maintenance of PHP app is much easier than VCL file... :)